# MySQL installation and unInstallation

Tags: mysql

How can we uninstall MySQL completely from the Windows OS ? So that we can freshly install MySQL.

Comment: Are you having issues with the standard uninstaller?

Answer (score 0):

For a "basic uninstall" just MySQL no GUI/ODBC etc,

Click START button, click RUN type APPWIZ.CPL and hit OK.

Find MySQL Server 5.X and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Windows you are running.  If its the XP style, then go to Control Panel -> Add/Remove programs.  If it's the new style (Vista/Win7), then it would be something like Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Programs and Features portion and just run the uninstall of MySQL.